# Корректировка размеров экрана

Tags: java, android

В процессе написания простой программы-рисовалки возникла проблема с работой под мое устройство. Экран 2960х1440, но при использовании данной конструкции

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

я получаю экран размером 2094x1080.

Каким образом происходит такая корректировка? У меня установлен флаг на скрытие заголовка и работы на полном экране, но не скрыта навигационная панель.

Есть ли способ работать с **полным** экраном или надо узнать про подобную корректировку и всегда учитывать её для разных устройств?

Comment: Ну что бы сказать что то определенное надо ходя бы разметку посмотреть.

Comment: Пробовали другие решения этой задачи? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels Может в настроках смартона указано другое разрешение?